# what is the purpose of extending outer class by a final static inner class?

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes, composition

in Spring, the `RestTemplate` has a class called `HttpClientErrorException`. in this class, we have a class for each http status. for example, for `Unauthorized` http status, we have a class like this:

```
public static final class Unauthorized extends HttpClientErrorException {
    private Unauthorized(String statusText, HttpHeaders headers, byte[] body, @Nullable Charset charset) {
        super(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, statusText, headers, body, charset);
    }
```

my question is why an inner class needs to extends and inherits its outer class?
in the body of the `Unauthorized` class, we've only used its parent constructor. then they've placed this class as an inner class?

EDIT:
there is an usage of this inner class in the body of outer class:

```
public static HttpClientErrorException create(@Nullable String message, HttpStatus statusCode,
            String statusText, HttpHeaders headers, byte[] body, @Nullable Charset charset) {

        switch (statusCode) {

            ...
            ...

            case UNAUTHORIZED:
                return message != null ?
                        new HttpClientErrorException.Unauthorized(message, statusText, headers, body, charset) :
                        new HttpClientErrorException.Unauthorized(statusText, headers, body, charset);
```

Comment: What design would *you* have gone for instead of this? Move `Unauthorized` out of `HttpClientErrorException`?

Comment: @Sweeper yes. maybe.

Comment: BTW there are no "*static inner class*"es; per Java Language Specification [8.1.3. Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3): "An *inner class* is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly `static`."

Comment: @matt As the previous commenter says, Java doesn't have "static inner classes". Inner classes are by definition non-static.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel `public class A{ class B{}; static class C{}; }` ? Are you calling those classes something other than inner? I always thought "inned" included those. Also, B would be tied to an instance of class A and C is not tied to an instance of A.

Comment: @matt They are called (static) **nested** classes. In your example, class `B` is an inner class (a.k.a a non-static nested class) and class C is a static nested class.

Comment: @matt Yes, C is only a nested class, B is called an inner class because when constructed it requires an instance of its enclosing class, while C does not. See also the quote and link by user16320675 above.

Comment: In this case, it is just a convenience place to put an implementation in an easy location to reference. A "static inner" class is just another class. It is only for naming at that point. The fact the class extends the outter class is because it is an implementation. It isn't a general feature for inner classes, it is just something the author did.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I would say this is a bit more explicit about when there is a [static modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.4) it just says they're no longer inner classes. Cheers.

Comment: What's surprising about this?  It's the same as putting it as an outer class, it just organizes things in one type.  (And it lets factory methods in the outer class access private constructors on the inner class, which is handy.)